# how to make drupal use mysqlnd_ms

Tags: database

I have installed mysqlnd_ms plugin , created the mysqlnd_ms.json with following configuration.

```
{
  "myapp": {
    "master": {
      "master_1": {
        "host": "mysql://drupal@1x4.xx6.x.1x9",
        "port":  3306,
        "user": "drupal",
        "password": "password",
        "db": "site2"
      }
    },
    "slave": {
      "slave_0": {
        "host": "mysql://drupal@1xx.1x1.xx9.2x1",
        "port":  3306,
        "user": "drupal",
        "password": "password",
        "db": "site1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

its still not splitting the queries! how will drupal work withmynsqlnd. Do i have make edits in setting.php

Comment: What hostname do you have in the DB details in settings.php?

Comment: hostname = myapp   this is my settings.php database array  <pre>$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'site2',
      'username' => 'drupal',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'myapp',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
</pre>

Comment: You've already done everything you need from a Drupal point of view then. Drupal uses that host name to create the PDO connection; the docs page for the plugin says that's all you need to do to use it

Comment: i am getting this error  : Warning: PDO::exec(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in DatabaseConnection_mysql->__construct() (line 69 of /var/www/html/site2/includes/database/mysql/database.inc).

Comment: I'd guess the plugin isn't installed/configured correctly then. Try a basic PHP page with a single connection to PDO, following the example on the docs page. If that doesn't work, you know it's the server and not Drupal

Answer (score 0):

That extension's operations are transparent to the application, you only need to configure the host that the DB connection is setup with.

From a Drupal point of view, you just need to update the "host" entry for the relevant database in settings.php to match the name of your mysqlnd_ms application. From the looks of your config file that's `myapp`, so your database connection might look like this:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'foo',
  'username' => 'bar',
  'password' => 'baz',
  'host' => 'myapp',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

If that doesn't work, check that the extension is installed, configured, and enabled.

Comment: it got resolved , the mistake i did was "host": "mysql://drupal@1x4.xx6.x.1x9". it should be host ip alone "host": 1x4.xx6.x.1x9". Thanks for the help. Also Adding ' "lazy_connections": 0"' got rid of  string related error "(mysqlnd_ms) string escaping doesn't work without established connection".  Thanks for the help

Comment: some how drush seems to be incompatible it gives me following error.  No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.